# Compare substrings in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to display only items where the link starts with 'https://'. I was thinking to compare a substring to a specific string in *ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="item.link | slice:0:8 == 'https://'">
    <div class="title">
      <a class="title-pointer" href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I imported the Pipe and PipeTransform from /@angular/core and slice seems to work:

```
{{item.link | slice:0:8}}
```

the output: https://

Why doesn't it work if I compare a sting to a substing in *ngIf?
What should I modfify?

Comment: Did you try to use parenthesis to help out? i.e. `*ngIf="(item.link | slice:0:8) === 'https://'"` I often need to do this in order for the pipes and everything to work out right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the solution from @DanielWStrimpel in the comments may work, the re-usability of this throughout the application is about zero.

I would recommend creating a general application wide service which can handle this process for you:

```
export class AppService {
  // match 'https://'
  public isHttps(link: string){
    return link.indexOf("https://") >= 0;
  }
  // match a provided string
  public match(link: string, match: string){
    return link.indexOf(match) >= 0;
  }
}
```

This way now you could also match any provided string as desired, such as a subdomain or even if you wanted to exclude `https://` link from site X

So your `*ngIf` would be:

```
<div *ngIf="appService.isHttps(item.link)">
```

or if you wanted to match a `https://` link and exclude sites from `stackoverflow.com`:

```
<div *ngIf="appService.isHttps(item.link) && !appService.match('stackoverflow.com')">
```

This will also be faster, performance wise, than splitting the string and doing this evaluation twice like you would have to with a `pipe`.

Here is a working example with the service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aegndv

---

*Note: Name the service something more appropriate of course.*